# How migrations to other stack exchange sites happen, Only Option is Ethereum Meta?

Tags: discussion

I have seen questions being migrated to other different stack exchange sites. How does this process happen?

I have seen questions asking help for JavaScript related issues in this site that can be clearly identified as StackOverflow questions. However when I try to mark them close as ***offtopic*** and select the option ***This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*** only option available is this meta site.

[image]

How to suggest them to be migrated to other stack exchange site? It becomes available only after certain privilege level or only moderators can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question.

I'm not sure what the proper process should be for the scenario you've outlined - one of the mods may be able to provide a definitive answer.

Each time I attempt to use the migration option, I end up asking myself the same question as you've asked, and wondering what the proper process should be... Without then asking on Meta :-)

What I normally end up doing is flag as off-topic, then use the "*Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)*" option, and then manually suggest the other site that it should be migrated to. Again, this may or may not be the most desirable way of doing things.

EDIT: as per a linked [answer](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1288) in @greenonline's post , apparently this feature is only available for moderators.

> Migrating to an arbitrary stack exchange site This is only an option
>   for ♦ moderators, so instead of voting to close the question † you
>   should flag it for moderator attention ‡ with a suggestion of where it
>   should be migrated.
>
> On established sites, migration paths are created to allow migration
>   without moderator approval, but any migrations outside of those
>   pathways still have to be handled by a moderator

The above provided solution of manually suggesting the site by using other option or flagging for moderator intervention are the options.

Comment: @RichardHarrocks thank you for the answer. Will see if there's any other process.

Comment: I would like to have an option to migrate questions to StackOverflow, as some of the questions are more of JavaScript / React programming questions than questions related to Ethereum.

Comment: and general block-chain questions as well

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It is because SE.Ethereum is still in beta. When it graduates, then more options will become available in that dialog to which you refer.</strike>

See [this answer](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/why-does-the-migrate-dialog-only-list-arduino-meta#answer-2341) to [Why does the migrate dialog only list Arduino Meta?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/why-does-the-migrate-dialog-only-list-arduino-meta)

Comment: Thank you, but I doubt Ethereum SE is still in beta. It is already graduated, isn't it? The comments and the linked answer at http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/closing-a-question-only-option-for-another-site-is-robotics-meta says it's an option only for mods. Will see if any mod will answer this.

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake - you're quite right, I've just checked Area 51 and it graduated 11 months ago..! Sorry about that.